# How to tell why OSX Code Signature is invalid

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, codesign

I have an OSX app I built with unity.  Runs fine until I sign it with codesign and then it fails with exception

```
   Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
   Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
   Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

Is there any way to get more information about why the code signature is invalid?

I signed it with a Developer ID certificate from an active Apple Developer account:

```
codesign -f --deep -s "Developer ID Application: Ro Anders" --entitlements adventure.entitlements ./adventure.app/
```

and then verified it with

```
codesign -dv --verbose=4 adventure.app
```

and the response doesn't report any problems

```
Executable=/Users/ro/multiplayer-adventure/H2HAdventure/target/OSX/adventure.app/Contents/MacOS/adventure
Identifier=com.h2hadventure.adventure
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=346 flags=0x0(none) hashes=3+5 location=embedded
VersionPlatform=1
VersionMin=657664
VersionSDK=658432
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=8b8a11c38e8cbe2fb7934f528bcc6ea0763c7291
CandidateCDHash sha256=f50657e61a2183b5a28bd651914a0994421ecbe3
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
Page size=4096
CDHash=f50657e61a2183b5a28bd651914a0994421ecbe3
Signature size=9062
Authority=Developer ID Application: Ro Anders (7QCS2LM77Z)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=May 21, 2019 at 5:46:54 PM
Info.plist entries=15
TeamIdentifier=7QCS2LM77Z
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=203
Internal requirements count=1 size=188
```

I'm trying to get more details like is it an issue with my certificate or my entitlements or what.

Comment: Have you been able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to see valid code signing identities on your machine and verify your code signing exist and valid.

```
xcrun security find-identity -v -p codesigning
```

I suspect this code signing `8b8a11c38e8cbe2fb7934f528bcc6ea0763c7291` that you are using for code sign not valid.

One more thing check you are creating debug build or release build, for release build there should be distribution certificate in your keychain under login tab.